# Почему код не проходит условие?

Tags: java, scanner, ввод

Добрый день! В моём коде нужно было ввести что-то при помощи сканера...

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);  // создаём сканер
String v;                             // переменную для ввода
v = sc.nextLine();                    // вводим

if(v == "w") {                        // проверяем
   System.out.print("OK");
}else
   System.out.print("ERROR");
```

... И если это "w" то, по логике, должно вывести "OK", но выводит "ERROR".
Не могу понять почему так. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно использовать не "==", а equals, так как вы сравниваете значения.

```
if(v.equals("w")) {                        // проверяем
   System.out.print("OK");
```

Comment: @Николай Если проблема решена, [отметьте ответ как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) (слева от ответа должна быть серая галка, нажмите на нее).